# Recursive query to speed up system

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

My application reads a table with parent child relation. The application queries every level of the tree on his own and it really slow (must do multiple levels deep). I has searching for another solution and came to the recursive queries. With the examples that I have found I cannot map it to my data structure.

My structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [products].[BillOfMaterial](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [parentNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [warehouse] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [childNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [childDescription] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [qtyRequired] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [childItemClass] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [childItemType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [scrapFactor] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
    [bubbleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [operationNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [effectivityDate] [date] NULL,
    [discontinuityDate] [date] NULL,
    [companyID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BillOfMaterial] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Some example data:
[image]

When I query for parentNumber 1 it should give me all those rows:
[image]

And for parentNumber 3 the output must be:
[image]

Now I need all the children of a parent in a recursive way. How can I achieve this using only sql? (I'm using SQL server)

I tried already using the with statement in sql, but it will now give a lot of results.

```
WITH bom ( [id]
      ,[parentNumber]
      ,[warehouse]
      ,[sequenceNumber]
      ,[childNumber]
      ,[childDescription]
      ,[qtyRequired]
      ,[childItemClass]
      ,[childItemType]
      ,[scrapFactor]
      ,[bubbleNumber]
      ,[operationNumber]
      ,[effectivityDate]
      ,[discontinuityDate]
      ,[companyID] )
AS
(
    select * from [CR_ApplicationSuite].[products].[BillOfMaterial] where parentNumber IN ('F611882261', '2912435206')
UNION ALL
select b.* from [CR_ApplicationSuite].[products].[BillOfMaterial] b
INNER JOIN [CR_ApplicationSuite].[products].[BillOfMaterial] c on c.childNumber = b.parentNumber
)
SELECT *
FROM bom
```

Comment: You should not fetch everything at once. You need to load the only required data at a time. Even if you recursive query to fetch all data, it would be huge to transfer from SQL Server to Application. The application can also become non-responsive.

Comment: Non-responsive is not an issue on my application setup. The query is done on server side, the client just need to wait for his answer. I need all the data to show to the users.

Comment: Post the table structure, sample data and expected output in text format. Look [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) on how to post sql questions on forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a table variable for demonstration purposes.

For a recursive query you need to use the CTE within itself.

I included a rootParentNumber, so it's more obvious what the base parent was.

The WHERE clauses are commented in the example. 
Because you can either put a WHERE clause within the Recursive Query, or at the outer query. The former should be faster.

```sql
declare @BillOfMaterial  TABLE (
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [parentNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [warehouse] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [childNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [childDescription] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [qtyRequired] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [childItemClass] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [childItemType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [scrapFactor] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
    [bubbleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [operationNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [effectivityDate] [date] NULL,
    [discontinuityDate] [date] NULL,
    [companyID] [bigint] NOT NULL
);

insert into @BillOfMaterial (parentNumber, childNumber, warehouse, sequenceNumber, qtyRequired, bubbleNumber, operationNumber, companyID) values
('1','2','WH1',1,0,0,0,1),
('2','4','WH1',2,0,0,0,1),
('3','4','WH1',3,0,0,0,1),
('4','5','WH1',4,0,0,0,1),
('5','0','WH1',5,0,0,0,1);

WITH BOM 
AS
(
    select parentNumber as rootParentNumber, * 
    from @BillOfMaterial 
    --where parentNumber IN ('1','3')

    union all

    select bom.rootParentNumber, b.* 
    from BOM
    INNER JOIN @BillOfMaterial b 
    on (BOM.childNumber = b.parentNumber and b.childNumber <> '0')
)
SELECT 
 [rootParentNumber]
,[parentNumber]
,[childNumber]
,[id]
,[warehouse]
,[sequenceNumber]
,[childDescription]
,[qtyRequired]
,[childItemClass]
,[childItemType]
,[scrapFactor]
,[bubbleNumber]
,[operationNumber]
,[effectivityDate]
,[discontinuityDate]
,[companyID]
FROM BOM
--WHERE rootParentNumber IN ('1','3')
ORDER BY [rootParentNumber], [parentNumber], [childNumber]
;
```